# Raw Data Instead of Zonal Statistics in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5

I have 2 layers:

1) Shapefile contains about 15 features.
2) Satellite Imagery.

I would like to get pixel values of satellite imagery (reflectance) in each zone. However unlike 'Zonal Statistics' tool, I do not want statistical summary, rather all the pixel values (So I can further analyze them outside of ArcGIS environment).

Current Approach:
1) Select the feature and create new layer.
2) Clip image using this new layer.
3) Copy from attribute table.
4) Repeat for all features.

This is very time consuming and need to repeat the whole process each time I get new imagery.

Is it possible to automate this process? Specifically, is there a tool, which outputs all the values instead of statical summary?

Comment: There are many different ways. If your raste is not to big you can try convert raster to Points, intersect with zones, table to excel. Or use RasterToNumPyArray if you want output as Array and your raster is to big to convert to Point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can string those tools together in ArcMap using model builder. Suggest you look at the help file and read up on modelbuilder as that is how you automate repetitive tasks without any code. Alternatively there are several companies that run modelbuilder training just search the internet for those.

Comment: I understand basics of model builder and I plan to deploy it. However, I asked the question to confirm if a tool or method like 'Zonal Statistics' exist which instead of compile values --> calculate statistics, just stop at first step. (since it seems like something lot of people might use)